# Script compilation failed. for Azure Function App

Tags: c#, twilio, azure-functions

I have set up Twilio with a webhook to call a Function App.
I have the following code in my Function App

```
using System.Net;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    // dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
    // lots of commented out code
}
```

When the function runs the log shows the following error

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpTriggerCSharp1
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpTriggerCSharp1 ---> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.CompilationErrorException : Script compilation failed.
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.DotNetFunctionInvoker.CreateFunctionTarget(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\Description\DotNet\DotNetFunctionInvoker.cs : 327
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionLoader`1.GetFunctionTargetAsync[T](Int32 attemptCount) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\Description\FunctionLoader.cs : 0
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.DotNetFunctionInvoker.GetFunctionTargetAsync() at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\Description\DotNet\DotNetFunctionInvoker.cs : 191
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.DotNetFunctionInvoker.InvokeCore(Object[] parameters,FunctionInvocationContext context) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\Description\DotNet\DotNetFunctionInvoker.cs : 259
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionInvokerBase.Invoke(Object[] parameters) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\Description\FunctionInvokerBase.cs : 90
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.VoidTaskMethodInvoker`2.InvokeAsync[TReflected,TReturnType](TReflected instance,Object[] arguments)
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.InvokeAsync[TReflected,TReturnValue](Object instance,Object[] arguments)
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.InvokeAsync(IFunctionInvoker invoker,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,CancellationTokenSource timeoutTokenSource,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource,Boolean throwOnTimeout,TimeSpan timerInterval,IFunctionInst…
```

Is a call to await required?
If I un-comment that call I still get the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important that you should not have any compilation errors. Make sure you are returning something using await or response

```
public static async Task Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, $"Current Time : {DateTime.Now}");    
}
```